# Repeatable Collection in Java

Tags: java, collections

I was wondering if we had a repeatable key , value function in java ?
I'm working on some key value with Hashtable .The problem is I can't add any key that has been existed in the table .
would you happen to know any method for that ?

this is a part of my code :

```
public class SymbolTable {
   public static Hashtable<Object,Object> rows = new Hashtable<>();
//    Hashtable
    static int counter=1;
    public void addKeyword(Object keyword){
        rows.put(keyword,counter);
        counter++;
    }
    public void InstallID(){
    rows.put("id ",counter);
    counter++;
    }
    public void otherTokens(String lexeme,Object attribute){
        rows.put(lexeme,attribute);
        counter++;
    }
    public void addnumber(String lexeme , Object attribute){
        rows.put(lexeme,attribute);
        counter++;
    }

    public Hashtable gettokens(){
        return rows;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: You realize `otherTokens` and `addnumber` are apart from their name _identical_ ?

Comment: Why are you variables `static`? Why are you using a legacy `Hashtable` instead of a `HashMap`? What is the purpose of this code, exactly? You are putting the value of  `counter` each time `addKeyword` is invoked with the same key, overwriting the previous one. Do you really want to have multiple integers associated with the key instead? And how do these integers interact with the other, arbitrary objects, `otherTokens` or `addnumber` will put into the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing in the Java standard library.

One option is to create a `Hashmap` whose values are `ArrayList`s. Wrap this into your own class for ease of use.

You could also use a ready-made implementation, for example, [Multimap](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap) from the Guava library.

Comment: Thank you so much ...I'll try the arrayList Thing .